# MySQL Sink Connector - JsonConverter - DataException: Unknown schema type: null

Tags: mysql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have created MySQL sink connector and successfully run and i see the logs and got 200 response,  But the sink connector not able to push the data into mysql db (data is available  in the topic)

```json
{ 
"name":"mysql-sink-connector", 
"config":{ "tasks.max":"2", 
"batch.size":"1000", 
"batch.max.rows":"1000", 
"poll.interval.ms":"500", 
"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector", 
"connection.url":"jdbc:mysql://mysql.azure.com:3306/db_test_dev", 
"table.name.format":"tbl_clients_merchants",
"topics":"createorder", 
"connection.user":"user", 
"connection.password":"password", 
"auto.create":"true", 
"auto.evolve":"true", 
"value.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter", 
"value.converter.schemas.enable":"true", 
"key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter", 
"key.converter.schemas.enable":"true" 
}}
```

getting an error

```
[2021-07-29 09:41:03,157] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=jdbc-mysql-sink-connector-1} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:177) org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler 
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error: 
at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:344)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Unknown schema type: null 
at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.convertToConnect(JsonConverter.java:743 
at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162) ... 13 more 
[2021-07-29 13:26:11,347] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=mysql-sink-connector-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:178)
```

Comment: That output includes no error. You'd need to show your database logs to prove that requests are being made. Please [edit] your question rather than use comments

Comment: @OneCricketeer am updated all code and error logs in the below mention URL can you please help on this issue .                                                                                                 URL: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-13163

Comment: You cannot open JIRAs for MySQL connector because that is a Confluent product, not Apache. That being said, your config is clearly using `FileStreamSinkConnector`, which does not accept a `connection.url` or any JDBC properties, so I am very confused what your problem is, and I asked you to [edit] your question here, not create a JIRA

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, you have null tombstone records in the topic, which cannot be mapped to any MySQL columns since there are no field names.

Option 1) Fix your producer to not send these messages

Option 2) [Filter them in Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/filter-ak.html)

For example,

```json
"transforms": "Filter",
"transforms.Filter.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Filter",
"transforms.Filter.predicate" : "DropNull",

"predicates" : "DropNull",
"predicates.DropNull.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.predicates.RecordIsTombstone"
```